# PHP table displaying blank values

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm building a forum page and this is my first PHP project. I've managed to connect my table and store values within PHPMYADMIN but they're not displaying on my main forum page, what does happen instead is the rows displayed will increment but they'll store empty values, any advice?

```
<?php

include ('includes/session.php');
include ('includes/header.php');

$host = "localhost";
$username = "fses16g6";
$password = "fses16g6";
$db_name="fses16g6"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="forum_question"; // Table name 
// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY id DESC";
// OREDER BY id DESC is order result by descending 

$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>

<table width="90%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1"        bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td width="6%" align="center" bgcolor="#000000"><strong>#</strong></td>
<td width="53%" align="center" bgcolor="#000000"><strong>Topic</strong></td>
<td width="15%" align="center" bgcolor="#000000"><strong>Views</strong></td>
<td width="13%" align="center" bgcolor="#000000"><strong>Replies</strong>    </td>
<td width="13%" align="center" bgcolor="#000000"><strong>Date/Time</strong> </td>
</tr>

<?php

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a href="view_topic.php?id=<? echo $rows['id']; ?>">    <echo $rows['topic']; ?></a><BR></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['view']; ?></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['reply']; ?></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['datetime']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
// Exit looping and close connection 
}

mysql_close();
?>
<tr>
<td colspan="5" align="right" bgcolor="#black"><a href="create_topic.php">    <strong>Create New Topic</strong> </a></td>
</tr> 
</table>
<?php
//if ($is_user) {

    //echo 'Welcome to Gamers Paradise' 

//else echo 'You must be logged in to post.' 
            //}
if ($is_admin) {
                echo '<button type="button">EDIT</button>';
                echo '<button type="button">DELETE</button>';
            }

include ('includes/footer.html');
?>
```

Here's the table

```
CREATE TABLE `forum_question`  
(`id` int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,`topic` varchar(255) NOT NULL default'',  

`detail` longtext NOT NULL,  
`name` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',  
`email` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',  
`datetime` varchar(25) NOT NULL default '',  
`view` int(4) NOT NULL default '0',  
`reply` int(4) NOT NULL default '0',  
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: you're just assuming that the query succeeded. `$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: Try `mysql_fetch_assoc($result)` instead of `mysql_fetch_array($result)`.  And then don't use `mysql_*` extensions anymore; use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: im betting its the short tags. change the `<?` to `<?php` and see if that works

Comment: You stated that the values are stored as empty values. Are you refering to them in the database? If so, this usually points to incorrect data types or field lengths. For example, trying to store a string as an integer, or a field with a max character limit of 10 but instead your trying to store 20. And so on... Could you post your insert queries and table structure?

Comment: Also `<echo $rows['topic']; ?>` may be causing you issues too. This should be `<?php echo $rows['topic']; ?>`

Comment: @MattKent I've added the table to my post
I am now able to display the date/time and the # of views on a post but not the comments or the 'id'.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

to...

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
```

You're trying to access your results as an associative array, so you need to fetch them from the database as an associative array as well.

But more importantly, you need to stop using `mysql_*` functions.  They are deprecated and insecure.

Comment: nope "Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or FALSE if there are no more rows. The type of returned array depends on how result_type is defined. By using MYSQL_BOTH (**default**), you'll get an array with both associative and number indices. " http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: Hmm. I tried this, still not displaying any results.
Each time I add a post, it increments and displays a new row, but still no text.

Answer (score 0):

As [Dagon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557846/dagon) and [matt kent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3375180/matt-kent) pointed out, my echo tags were missing the opening php demarcation, this was causing none of the values to display.

So, instead of:

`<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?echo $rows['view']; ?></td>`

I needed:

`<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><php?echo $rows['view']; ?></td>`

This did this with all of the rows and they are not displaying.

Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: @Dagon, sorry! I was in such a hurry to get it to work, I looked past what you had.